# Launch PHP script from cron?

Tags: php, cron

I know you need to put `/usr/local/bin/php -f` in cron before path to php file e.g.

```
/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/public_html/scrip.php
```

but should i use `-q` or `-f`?

When i run `/usr/local/bin/php --help` it does not show any -q option yet many tutorials online say `-q`.

Answer (score 2):

The *-q* option just suppresses output from the PHP executable.  This is useful when running a PHP script as a cron job.  So really, you should use both.

See "man php" for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The `-q` stands for quiet mode which will suppress all the HTTP headers from being sent along with it. Anything outputted by the script will be *just* that output.

PHP has [full documentation on command line options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) on their website.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), `-q` does the following

> Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

You don't really need any options to run a PHP script from cron.

Comment: @JohnA: Yes, the CLI version of PHP already suppresses HTTP headers.

Comment: @JohnA: Correct.  There is no need to suppress output when used as Apache (or other web server) module.